# Is it impossible to cancel the transaction when my server is on error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paypal

Title : Is it impossible to cancel the transaction when my server is on error

I try to do [paypal checkout docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/).
This is client code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SmartPaymentButtons, { PayPalSDKWrapper } from 'react-smart-payment-buttons';

class PayPal extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <PayPalSDKWrapper clientId="<client_ID>">
                <SmartPaymentButtons
                    createOrder={(data, actions) => {
                        return actions.order.create({
                            purchase_units: [{
                                amount: {
                                    currency_code: "USD",
                                    value: "0.09"
                                }
                            }]
                        });
                    }}
                    onApprove={ (data, actions) => {

                        return actions.order.capture()
                            .then(async (details) => {
                            alert("Transaction completed by " + details.payer.name.given_name);
                            return axios({
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: 'http://localhost:5002/paypal/paypal-transaction-complete',
                                data: {
                                    orderID: data.orderID
                                },
                            }).then(res =>   {
                                return res.data;
                            })
                        });
                    }}
                />
            </PayPalSDKWrapper>
        );
    }
}

export default PayPal;
```

And this is nodejs code

```js
const checkoutNodeJssdk = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk');

const payPalClient = require('../Common/payPalClient');

module.exports = async function handleRequest(req, res) {

  const orderID = req.body.orderID;

  let request = new checkoutNodeJssdk.orders.OrdersGetRequest(orderID);

  let order;
  try {
    order = await payPalClient.client().execute(request);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.send(500);
  }

  // sending error on purpose
  if (order.result.purchase_units[0].amount.value !== '220.00') {
    return res.send(400);
  }

  // Save the transaction in your database
  // <...saving orderID code...>

  return res.send(200);
}
```

I made an error on my server on purpose. So `orderID` didn't save. It's what I expected. But The paypal paid money. I didn't get orderID in my DB, but paid already in paypal.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: i think only solution would be using the refund api. Maybe you run a cronjob every day or every hour to figure out these kind of requests. and then run the refund apis for those orders. Most companies do this via support person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once this line of your code has run, the payment is executed and cannot be "cancelled". It will need to be refunded manually or via the API.

```
order = await payPalClient.client().execute(request);
```

It looks like you are using the server-side implementation to approve the transaction which is good, but you are using the client-side (createOrder) implementation to setup the transaction.

Instead of calling "actions.order.create", you should make a POST request to your server to create the transaction, similar to your onApprove method. From here, you can pass your server all variables such as the price, item name, delivery address etc, and then perform your verification before approving payment in the onApprove method.

Your client side createOrder function should look similar to this (from PayPal Docs):

```
createOrder: function() {
  return fetch('/my-server/create-paypal-transaction', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
       value: 200.00
    }
  }).then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    return data.orderID;
  });
}
```

Example server-side code from PayPal docs, with your value verification IF statement between steps 2 and 3:

```
// 1. Set up your server to make calls to PayPal

// 1a. Import the SDK package
const paypal = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk');

// 1b. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side 
  SDK`.
  /**
   *
   * PayPal HTTP client dependency
   */
  const payPalClient = require('../Common/payPalClient');

// 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
module.exports = async function handleRequest(req, res) {

// sending error on purpose
if (req.body.value !== '220.00') {
  return res.send(400);
}

  // 3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
  const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
  request.prefer("return=representation");
  request.requestBody({
    intent: 'CAPTURE',
    purchase_units: [{
      amount: {
        currency_code: 'USD',
        value: '220.00'
      }
    }]
  });

  let order;
  try {
    order = await payPalClient.client().execute(request);
  } catch (err) {

    // 4. Handle any errors from the call
    console.error(err);
    return res.send(500);
  }

  // 5. Return a successful response to the client with the order ID
  res.status(200).json({
    orderID: order.result.id
  });
}
```

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/

Comment: I solved with the link you wrote for `createOrder` and [capture transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/) for `onApprove`. Thank you so much. :)